# Is irreversible work a path function?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

In $P/V$ plots of irreversible processes only initial and final state is defined due to sudden compression or rarefaction then how is work done a path function in irreversible processes.

[image: Irreversible process]
[image: Isothermal irreversible expansion PV graph]

Why won't work done by the process here be only dependent on initial and final states?

Comment: Can someone please tell me why is this classified as a homework question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any process, the work done by the gas on the surroundings is $\int{P_\mathrm{ext}\,\mathrm dV},$ where $P_\mathrm{ext}$ is the force per unit area the piston exerts on the gas at the piston face, and also the force per unit area the gas exerts on the piston at the piston face.  For a reversible process, $P_\mathrm{ext}$ is also equal to $P,$ the pressure calculated from the equation of state for the gas (such as the ideal gas law).  But, for an irreversible process it is not determined by the equation of state, due mainly to viscous stresses within the gas.

So, if you can plot $P_\mathrm{ext}$ vs $V$ on the graph, you can correctly calculate the work, but, for an arbitrary irreversible process where $P_\mathrm{ext}$ is not adequately controlled externally, this is not always possible.

Comment: I had a doubt whether such graphs are  possible for Irreversible processes where P and V aren't defined properly during the process.Can such a graph be plotted experimentally?

Comment: Sure.  Just place a flush mounted pressure transducer in the piston face contacting the gas.  This is a direct measurement of $P_{ext}$.

Answer (score 2):

From *Fundamentals of Thermodynamics* by Borgnakke and Sonntag [1, p. 94]:

> Further consideration of a $P-V$ diagram, such as Fig. 4.6, leads to another important conclusion.
>   It is possible to go from state 1 to state 2 along many different quasi-equilibrium paths, such as *A*, *B*, or *C*. Since the area under each curve represents the work for each process, the amount of work done during each process not only is a function of the end states of the process but also depends on the path followed in going from one state to another.
>   For this reason, work is called a path function or, in mathematical parlance, $\delta W$ is an inexact differential.
>
> [image: Fig. 4.6 P-V diagram]
>
> **FIGURE 4.6** Various quasi-equilibrium processes between two given states, indicating that work is a path function.

Because work is a path function. It doesn't matter your process is reversible or irreversible. If you just consider the initial and final state, but go from two different paths, you'll have two different answers. For example, in the picture I uploaded, the areas under curve *A* and *B* are different. Therefore, work is different. But, as you can see, the final and initial states are the same.

#### References

1. Borgnakke, C.; Sonntag, R. E. *Fundamentals of Thermodynamics*, 7th ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, NJ, **2009**. ISBN 978-0-470-04192-5.

Comment: As for the text, again, there is very rarely a need for posting a screenshot: Chemistry.SE provides a wide variety of formatting utilities for a precise reproduction of the quoted text. Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: @andselisk Thank you. It's the first time I'm answering. I will improve and edit it.

Comment: Just a doubt how is it possible to graph out the P and V during the process as the Thermodynamic Variables wont be properly defined due to sudden compressions and rarefactions. Can such a graph be made experimentally?

Comment: @paria I took a liberty to edit your post accordingly correcting citation, converting images to text and improving grammar; hopefully you find my this useful for your future contributions.

Comment: That figure is of a process in quasi-static equilibrium which would mean they are reversible reactions not Irreversible.

Comment: @AmeyaM As far as I know, we can determine work from other information we have, such as entropy or internal energy or efficiency.

Comment: @AmeyaM Diagrams are based on experience. They measure the volume in a specific pressure. And sometimes when it's not possible, they use extrapolation.

Comment: @AmeyaM For sudden compression it's not usual to find the diagram. But for doing so, we make some assumptions. In general, if you have just initial and final state you can't find work from diagram. You should use some properties as I said before.